Framework 'FlutterPluginRegistrant' not found
I am integrating a flutter module using cocoapods. I have created podfile as described in below document and did pod install and built the project but getting Framework 'FlutterPluginRegistrant not found' error.
https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/ios/project-setup
The module generates all framework using 'flutter build ios-framework' and works fine if integrated into existing iOS project.
